# Trying to split string into pieces and reverse

Tags: .net, substring, indexof

```
    Dim strFullName As String = txtFullName.Text

    Dim intFirstName As Integer = strFullName.IndexOf(" ")
    Dim strFirstName As String = strFullName.Substring(0, intFirstName)

    Dim intMiddleName As Integer = strFullName.IndexOf(" ", intFirstName + 1)
    Dim strMiddleName As String = strFullName.Substring(Name.IndexOf(" ") + 1)

    Dim intLastName As Integer = strFullName.LastIndexOf(" ", ((intFirstName) + (intMiddleName)))
    Dim strLastName As String = strFullName.Substring(2)
    txtReverseName.Text = (strLastName & "," & strFirstName & strMiddleName)
```

I'm trying to split the string strFullName into individual strings to then reverse into a format of Last, First Middle and output to a textbox. The out put is incorrect, [for example](http://prntscr.com/2ifvpa). If anyone has any ideas on to fix this situation I've been having that would be great.

Comment: Do you have any problem using String.Split?

Comment: I havent used String.Split in this code but i was wanting to use index of for this code i have been working on

Comment: All right then, but from a logical point of view, what happen if a person doesn't have a MiddleName?

Comment: First i want to get it to have it working with a middle then i would simply have an if saying if that spot isnt there then proceed with the else which would be lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your input to work with IndexOf, you could try this code.

```
Dim strFullName As String = txtFullName.Text
Dim strMiddleName As String = String.Empty
Dim strFirstName As String = string.Empty
Dim strLastName As String = string.Empty

' Search the first space position '
Dim spacePos As Integer = strFullName.IndexOf(" ")

' Check if user has inserted a space (spacePos is equal to -1 otherwise) '
if spacePos >= 0 Then
    ' Extract the string from the beginning to the space found '
    strFirstName = strFullName.Substring(0, spacePos)
    ' Now check if there is another space but starting from a position after the first one'
    Dim intMiddleName As Integer = strFullName.IndexOf(" ", spacePos + 1)
    ' Again check if there is a second space '
    if intMiddleName >= 0 Then
      ' Get the middle from a position after the first one and for a length of chars
      ' given by the second space position less the first space position '
      strMiddleName = strFullName.Substring(spacePos + 1, intMiddleName - spacePos)
      ' Advance to the next non space char '
      spacePos = intMiddleName + 1
    end if
    ' Take the last part of the string from whatever position the spacePos variable points to'
    strLastName = strFullName.Substring(spacePos)

    ' Rebuild as desired '
    txtReverseName.Text = (strLastName & "," & strFirstName & " " & strMiddleName)
End If
```

Keep in mind that this code is still really weak because your user could make numbers with that textbox (like writing two space consecutively)

Comment: Thank you so much me and a coding budy of mine were stuck on this and could fiqure out why the middlename was giving us an int value of 12 in the locals.

Comment: Also could you describe what its doing. Sort of like a stepbystep of what its doing like a break going step by step into the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim x As String = "a b c"
    Dim array = x.Split(" ")
    Dim y = array(2) + " " + array(0) + " " + array(1)
```

Produces:

"c a b"

Comment: Okay that does work but i need it to be grabbing the user imputed information to be switch